# set double when item selected Spinner - Android

Tags: android, textview, double, spinner

I have created a spinner with 3 options: Beginner, Advanced and Pro. When one of the options is selected, I want to create a toast and set a double. I need the double to use that value later on, to calculate with 2 other values from an edittext.
For developing purposes I want to set a textview with that value, to check it.
I have tried a few things, but I cant bring it work. The textview keeps displaying 0.0

Hope someone can help me.

My java code:

```
package tim.steunebrink.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlbumsActivity  extends Activity{


private TextView ExpValue;
private double expchosen;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.albums_layout);

    ExpValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExpValue);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_experience);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.experience_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                // Beginner
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Beginner = 0.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                double expchosen = new Double("0.5");

            } else if(pos == 1) {
                // Advanced
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Advanced = 1.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                double expchosen = new Double("1.0");

            } else {
                // Pro
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Pro = 1.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                double expchosen = new Double("1.5");

            }


            ExpValue.setText(Double.toString(expchosen));

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}   
}
```

Comment: is the toast generated when u click on any item of ur spinner?

Comment: yes it is. that works fine. its the double thats not working as it should be. did i set the value of it the right way??

Comment: got it working now. it is just: expchosen = 1.0; thats it. work fine now :)

Comment: or u can do it in the way defined below by me.suiting the way u previously worked with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make these Changes

```
class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        double expchosen ;
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                // Beginner
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Beginner = 0.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                expchosen= new Double("0.5");
            } else if(pos == 1) {
                // Advanced
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Advanced = 1.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                expchosen = new Double("1.0");
            } else {
                // Pro
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Pro = 1.5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                expchosen = new Double("1.5");
            }
            ExpValue.setText(Double.toString(expchosen));
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code may be useful to you.

Apply

```
ExpValue.invalidate();
```

After line

```
ExpValue.setText(Double.toString(expchosen));
```

Comment: yes, set editable to true in the xml. changing the text is not the problem as it displays "expvalue" before an item is chosen from the spinner. the problem is how to set the double expchosen.